# How to import a .dat file into Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

How to import a .dat file into Pycharm?

I am using data from a catalog (.dat file) for my research, and working in Pycharm. Note: This is my first time working in Pycharm. 
Any leads will be much appreciated!

Comment: I think you mean to ask how to import the data into your python script? PyCharm is an editor.

Comment: @nalyd88 Clearly, I'm a newbie to both Python and Pycharm. Yes! I'm used to working in Jupyter notebooks but have been experiencing problems, so I thought I would give Pycharm a try. In jupyter notebooks, using np.genfromtxt('file name') or ascii.read('file name') would easily read the .dat file, allowing me to work with the data in it. However, these commands don't seem to be working when I'm in Pycharm. I've imported the necessary packages, so my assumption is that the .dat file is not being read. Any ideas how fix this?

Comment: Please edit your question, clarify what you actually want to do, show what you have tried, how that failed. See this post for help forming good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. If you find that this question has already been asked and answered, you can retract this question.